# Qt slots and passing data

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots, slot

I am trying to make a script in which the Qml code can send data to the c++ script and then executes a function accordingly. This part is working fine, but i also want to send feedback from the executed function back to the Qml.

I have the following code (It is a stripped down example to test the sending of data from **Receiver.cpp** to the Qml)

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "receiver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    Receiver receiver;

    QQmlContext* ctx = engine.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("receiver", &receiver);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));


    return app.exec();
}
```

**Reciever.cpp**(Note: I am trying to send the data from this code too. I guess this is where it goes wrong)

```
#include "receiver.h"
#include <QDebug>

#include <QQmlApplicationEngine> //For sending to QML
#include <QQmlContext> //For sending to QML

Receiver::Receiver(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

int counter = 0;

void Receiver::receiveFromQml(int count) {
    qDebug() << "Received in C++ from QML:" << count;

    //For sending to QML start
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    Receiver receiver;

    QQmlContext* ctx = engine.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("receiver", &receiver);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    //For sending to QML end

    receiver.sendToQml(counter); //Send to the QML

    counter++;

}
```

**Reciever.h**

```
#ifndef RECEIVER_H
#define RECEIVER_H

#include <QObject>

class Receiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Receiver(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void sendToQml(int count);

public slots:
    void receiveFromQml(int count);

};

#endif // RECEIVER_H
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    id: test
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    property variant globalForJs: 10;

    Item {
        Timer {
            interval: 1000; running: true; repeat: true
            onTriggered: console.log("Real text value:", text1.text, " Global for JS:", globalForJs);
        }
    }



    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            receiver.receiveFromQml(42);
        }

        Text {
            id: text1
            x: 193
            y: 329
            text: globalForJs
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Press me to send a signal to C++")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Connections {
        target: receiver
        onSendToQml: {
            console.log("Received in QML from C++: " + count);
            globalForJs = count;
            console.log(text1.text);
            console.log("Real text value:2", text1.text, " Global for JS:", globalForJs);
        }
    }

}
```

I am using the timer to show the real values of *text1* and the global variable *GlobalForJs* I tried to make but which didn't work. Inside the *Connections* part it displays that the text in fact changes. But outside of the *Connections* it does not change.

My best guess is that it is due to the fact that I create a 'new' connection in the **receiver.cpp**

So in a short summary my question is: How can I send data from **receiver.cpp**(and in the future other cpp files) to the Qml file and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a lot of solutions:

1. Create a signal in `C++` code and connect to it in `qml` to be able to get results from C++ method.
2. Slots can be not only `void` but also return a value actually. But in this case it will block your thread and cause a "freeze".
3. Export an object with which you can interact fully. This is the most suitable way to do such things.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Do you happen to have a tutorial/extra explanation on the 3th solution? I am pretty new to Qt and can't really find any clear examples of how to do this.

Comment: @Martijn Read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html

Everything is nicely explained on the `doc.qt.io` about `C++` and `QML`. Information there can be used for novices. Look there for further questions first.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have read the document and followed the tutorial which is linked in the document and now i have got the code working.

Comment: Great news, @Martijn! Accept it as answer then to let people know that your problem is solvable.